# Trouble reading a file and putting it into a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to read a file with a line of numbers and put it into a 2d array

***Here is the prompt:***

Create a file of integers. Write a program that first tests whether the number of integers is a square of some integer n. If so, create a 2D array of size n×n. Then, read the numbers into the array. Finally, display the array and test whether the array forms a magic square, that is, whether the sums of rows, columns, and diagonals are all equal. For example, if the file includes numbers
6 7 2 1 5 9 8 3 4
so that n = 3, then the array
6 7 2
1 5 9
8 3 4
is displayed along with the message that the array is a magic square.

I have up to reading the file and putting it into an array but am stuck and I don't know how to put the numbers into the array I have made.
***Here is my Code so far:***

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
//import java.util.Arrays;
class Program8 {
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    void print2Darray(int[][] a){
    for(int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
      for(int col = 0; col < a[row].length ; col++)
        System.out.print(a[row][col] + " ");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  
  void magicSquare(){
    Scanner fIn;
    System.out.print("Enter the name of a file: ");
    String s = kb.nextLine();
    try {
      fIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(s));
      double x = 0;
     // double y = 0;
     // double z = 0;
      int cnt = 0;
      while(fIn.hasNextDouble()){
        x = fIn.nextDouble();
        cnt++;
        System.out.println(cnt);
      }
      int sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(cnt);
      System.out.println(sqrt);
      
      int [][] magicSqaure = new int [sqrt][sqrt];
      print2Darray(magicSqaure);
      //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream(s));
       while(fIn.hasNextDouble()){
        for (int i = 0; i < magicSqaure.length; i++){
          //input from file
          for(int j = 0; i < magicSqaure.length; j++)
         //input from file
          
        }
          //for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
         // z = fIn.nextDouble();
        
       //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(magicSqaure));
       // print2Darray(magicSqaure);
       }
    }catch(IOException e){
    }
  }
  

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Program8 lab = new Program8();
    lab.magicSquare();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are suppose to read a file which contains integers, why are you trying to read them in as double type? Why not use `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()`?

Comment: Because you've already read through the file once in order to count the numbers,,you'll need to read through it again in order to put the numbers in your 2d array.  And to do _that_, you'll need to close `fIn` and create a new `Scanner`( and `FileInputStream`).